# PyQT5 - position of widgets

Tags: pyqt5

I am currently doing an PyQT5 app and I want my widgets to be stacked something like this

[image]

Is it posible and if so how can I do it?

Comment: I suggest you to read more about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and do some experiments [using Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) to better understand how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QGridLayout:

```
grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
grid_layout.addWidget(widget1, 0, 0, 2, 2)
grid_layout.addWidget(widget2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
# and so forth
```

The method `addWidget` is used for placing a widget in a certain area. First two args after widget are the positions from top and from left. The other two are the height and width.

Your canvas can be seen as a grid layout of width 4 and height 2.

Comment: The grid is actually made of 3 columns, the first widget spans only one column, with the other starting at column `1`, and an appropriate stretch should be set (using [`setColumnStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch) to ensure that the proportion is correct: unused spans are completely ignored and considered as single rows or columns unless specific sizes or stretch are used. Also, if both row and column spans are 1, they can be omitted.